# How to pass a php variable in window.open function

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP loop ( WHILE{} ) that loops an array from MySQL and creates a page with the data line by line. I need to add to each line a button that will trigger a new page but I need to carry the value of the id of the line to that new pop-up page.  This is the code I have, but i can't figure out how to pass my id to the pop up:

I know I can't add my PHP variable to the URL in the JS function, because it sits outside the loop.  Can I use the JS function to add it ? Here is some simplified code:

> **PHP Code**

```
<?php
    while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($get_all)){

        $id= $all['id'];

        echo '<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='openWin()'>  Click here</button> ';

    }
?>
```

---

> **Javascript**

```
<script>
        var myWindow;

        function openWin() {
            myWindow = window.open("http://www.website.com/pop.php", "myWindow", "width=600,height=800");
        }

        function closeWin() {
            myWindow.close();
        }
</script>
```

I need to get $id to the new page.  As stated I was hoping to add it to the URL as a $_GET variable, but I don't seem to know how to add it since the url sits in the JS function outside the while loop.

Sorry for the poor indenting

Comment: The nested single-quotes in your `echo` are invalid

Comment: In your while loop may be multiple id's so you want to pass multiple id to URL or single id only?

Comment: single id ..it'a 3 digit number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just pass a parameter

```
while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($get_all)){

 $id= $all['id'];
 echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="openWin(\''.$id.'\')">  Click 
   here</button> ';
}



<script>
        var myWindow;
        function openWin(id) {
            myWindow = window.open("http://www.website.com/pop.php?p_id="+id, "myWindow", "width=600,height=800");
        }
        function closeWin() {
            myWindow.close();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: can you upload a screen shot

Comment: I know OP said the ID is a three-digit number but you should still be mindful of XSS vulnerabilities with this, both when injecting it into the HTML and when using it in the `window.open()` URL

Answer (score 2):

hope it will work for you.

```
while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($get_all)){
    ...
    $id= $all['id'];
    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='openWin($id)'>  Click here</button>";
    ...
    }

    <script>
            var myWindow;
            function openWin(id) {
                myWindow = window.open("http://www.website.com/pop.php?id="+id, "myWindow", "width=600,height=800");
            }
            function closeWin() {
                myWindow.close();
            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `id` as an attribute of your HTML `<button>` element and pass that to the `openWin` function, eg

```php
while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($get_all)) : ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="openWin(this.dataset.id)"
        data-id="<?= htmlspecialchars($all['id']) ?>">
  Click here
</button>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

and in your JS

```js
function openWin(id) {
  myWindow = window.open(
      `http://www.website.com/pop.php?id=${encodeURIComponent(id)}`,
      'myWindow',
      'width=600,height=800'
  )
}
```

---

I've used an HTML attribute to store the value (as opposed to just injecting it into the `onclick` expression) to avoid the issue of having to simultaneously HTML and JS encode the value.

I've also used `data-id` instead of just `id` because a 3-digit number makes a bad HTML element ID, prone to easy conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

### 2 steps to follow

1. Pass your php variable ***$id*** to javascript function using function-call-by-value reference,
2. then use that argument in GET request for url to be opened in new window

   ```
   $id= $all['id'];
   echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='openWin(".$id.")'>  Click     here</button> ";

   }
   ?>
   <script>
   var myWindow;
   function openWin(id) {
   myWindow = window.open("http://www.website.com/pop.php?id="+id, "myWindow", "width=600,height=800");
   }
   function closeWin() {
   myWindow.close();
   }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies or HTML5 localStorage if its purely on the client-side.

> **Simple jQuery (Pass as a query string in the URL)**

```
<script>
        var myWindow;
        function openWin(id) {
            myWindow = window.open("http://www.website.com/pop.php?p_id="+id, "myWindow", "width=600,height=800");
        }
        function closeWin() {
            myWindow.close();
        }
</script>
```

> **Example 2 Simple jQuery (Pass as a query string in the URL via function)**

```
function set_url_data(go_to_url, data) {
  new_url = go_to_url + '?data=' + data;
  window.location.href = new_url;
}
```

> **LocalStorage**

```
//Set data

    localStorage.setItem('bookedStatus' + customerId, true);

    //Get data

    localStorage.getItem('bookedStatus');
```

> **Ajax**

```
<script>
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: package.php,
       data: $("#myform").serialize(), 
       success: function(data)
       {
           $('#Result').html(data); 
       }
    });
</script>
```